# frameset column height

Tags: xhtml, frameset

i want to create a page with frame set 
first i divide the page in 3 rows. In second row i divide it  by 2 coloumns. My problem is that first column of the second row contain lot of content(a full screen height), so there is  a scroll bar , I want to  show  all the  content without scrolling..., is it possible ??? 
can i give height to the column ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have your frameset something like this:

```
<frameset rows="100,*,80">
  <frame src="f1.htm"/>
  <frameset cols="120,*">
    <frame src="left.htm"/>
    <frame src="right.htm"/>
  </frameset>
  <frame src="f2.htm"/>
</frameset>
```

Which will look something like this:

```
________________________
| f1.htm               |
|______________________|
|          |           |
| left.htm | right.htm |
|__________|___________|
| f2.htm               |
|______________________|
```

If you want the left.htm to fill the entire height in the window, you need to re-structure to this:

```
<frameset cols ="120,*">
  <frame src="left.htm"/>
  <frameset rows="100,*,80">
    <frame src="f1.htm"/>
    <frame src="right.htm"/>
    <frame src="f2.htm"/>
  </frameset>
</frameset>
```

Which will look something like this:

```
________________________
|          | f1.htm    |
|          |___________|
| left.htm |           |
|          | right.htm |
|          |___________|
|          | f2.htm    |
|__________|___________|
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting height to * should work...

```
<frameset blabla height="*">
```

Bobby